# How to recognize whether the $t$ value is significant?

Tags: statistical-significance

How can I distinguish that `t-value` in LISREL is significant at 0.01 or 0.05, or 0.1?
I mean, if we have a path with `0.30` and `t-value=2.60`, `df=110`, is it significant at 0.01 or 0.05, or 0.1?

Comment: That depends on the number of degrees of freedom you have left. If you have the degrees of freedom you can look up the necessary values in the appropriate table that usually apears at the end of any introductory stats textbook.

Answer (score 0):

if the degrees of freedom is pretty big, then the cutoffs for 0.01, 0.05, 0.1 are about 2.58, 1.96, and 1.65. when the degrees of freedom is smaller, these critical values get larger. for that, i would either figure out how to calculate areas under the t-distribution in your software package, or acquaint yourself with t-distribution tables that appear in most introductory stats books, like this one

http://slidewiki.org/upload/media/images/141/6503.jpg?filter=Resize-width-340